# Error delivering iOS App update. "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK."

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store

I reticently delivered an app to the iOS App store on 1/24/2014. It's an iO7/iPhone only app and everything was delivered correctly. As of yesterday my app was approved and it is currently visible in the App Store.

I put together a small update and am currently working on getting it delivered using Application Loader.

However, now when I upload my production IPA it gets rejected due to what seems like a sdk error.

```
Messages:
    Apple's web service operation was not successful
    Unable to authenticate the package: 806906410.itmsp
    ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

I'm struggling to figure out what has changed since I am building with the same SDK as I did last weekend.

Comment: Are you building against the iOS 7 SDK?  As of February 1st 2014 Apple requires new submissions to be built against the iOS 7 SDK, whereas previously you could have built against the 6.1 SDK.

Comment: Which version of xcode are you using? If you don't have the latest version yet try to update it. I have Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I missed this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the February 1st you can use only XCode 5.X and iOS7 SDK to create apps for the AppStore. Double check that you compiled your app with the correct XCode/SDK.

Information about this: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a

Comment: And to avoid any confusion, you can still support iOS 6 and earlier if needed by setting the "Deployment Target" appropriately. But the Base SDK must now be iOS 7.0 or later.

Answer (score 3):

I was hoping your suggestion works but I got the error despite using Air 4.0 SDK. I didn't get this error when I uploaded it to the App Store a few days ago (I was already using Air 4.0 then). Does it really mean that Apple has limited development to using Xcode?

**EDIT:**

Updating to Air 4.0 SDK does work! But make sure what you have is **Air 4.0 SDK for Flex Developers**

Answer (score 2):

For Flex users with the same error message: you have to download the AIR 4.0 SDK beta from Adobe Lab:
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html
(for me, it was SDK for Flex, Mac)
Then extract it (sudo tar jxvf air4-0_sdk_sa_mac.tbz2) and overlay it with the Flex SDK as explain in:
http://www.247sw.ca/installing-flash-builder-4-7-and-air-3-5-for-windows-and-mac

Publishing to the AppStore is OK after that.

Comment: I have update my air SDK then I have submit a new app through application loader. It was accepted. Now, I have an old app. I am trying to submit its updated version, but it shows me same error. What should I do now? Any idea

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, i updated the Air 4.0 SDK, and it works fine! Make sure to update Air 4.0 SDK for Flex Developers. Please set xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0" inside --app.xml configuration file.

You can download the latest sdk from http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, however in my case, the reason was because I had the latest Xcode beta for iOS 8 on my computer. Event I built from Xcode 5.1.1 GUI, the beta compiler was picked. Had to move beta to trash first to make a build for the store.